# Change Sign In With Apple button style based on current color scheme

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-environment

I'm having some issues with SwiftUI's `SignInWithAppleButton`'s `signInWithAppleButtonStyle`. I am trying to change the color of the button based on the user's current scheme or if it changes.
This is iOS 14 and SwiftUI:

```
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var currentScheme
@State var appleButtonWhite = false

VStack{
SignInWithAppleButton(
                .signUp,
                onRequest: { request in              
                    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
                },
                onCompletion: { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success (let authResults):
                        print("Authorization successful.")
       
                    case .failure (let error):
                        print("Authorization failed: " + error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            )
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .signInWithAppleButtonStyle(appleButtonWhite ? .white : .black)
}
.onChange(of: currentScheme, perform: { (scheme) in
        if scheme == .light
        {
            appleButtonWhite = false
        }
        else
        {
            appleButtonWhite = true
        }
    })
```

When `appleButtonWhite` changes values, it renders the view as it should since the state is changing. When I debug the button it has the correct appleButtonWhite value, but for some reason the style just never changes. I have no idea why. I have done many style changes in my code with regular buttons and it works correctly based on different states. Any ideas why Apple's doesn't change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to solve this by moving the `SignInWithAppleButton` to its own View, without `signInWithAppleButtonStyle`

Then using `@Environment(\.colorScheme)` create an `if statement` and import the `SignInWithAppleButtonView` styling with `signInWithAppleButtonStyle`.

```
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var currentScheme
    
    var body: some View {
        if self.currentScheme == .light {
            SignInWithAppleButtonView()
                .signInWithAppleButtonStyle(.black)
        } else {
            SignInWithAppleButtonView()
                .signInWithAppleButtonStyle(.white)
        }
    }
}

struct SignInWithAppleButtonView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SignInWithAppleButton(
            .signUp,
            onRequest: {_ in },
            onCompletion: {_ in }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

We can write even more elegant solution. Based on the mrjohnsly answer above

Here's a resource that explain how to efficiently use Swift views https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var currentScheme
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SignInWithAppleButton { request in
                // request handeling
            } onCompletion: { result in
                // result handeling
            }
            .signInWithAppleButtonStyle(currentScheme == .light ? .black : .white) // <- here
            .frame(width: 250, height: 45, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. That was my issue originally. I just tried it now and it doesn't work. If you toggle the appearance the colors dont change. Im on iOS 15 and Xcode 13 and the solution seems to be the accepted answer. Not sure why it doesn't work the way you said unfortunately.

Comment: @EricAgredo maybe because you're using beta version of iOS 15. I tested on iOS 14.6 and Xcode 12 and it's working flawlessly